# Conditional WHERE clause using IN

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I have a sql query where I should have something like

```
select  * from transactionDetails
WHERE OrderID in (400376, 400379)
AND
    IF TransactionDate <> ProcessingDate
        TransactionId in (2,3,9,14,15)
    ELSE
        TransactionId in (2,3,9)
```

But this gives me a error at IF and TransactionId.

Then I tried

```
select  * from transactionDetails
WHERE OrderID in (400376, 400379)
AND
    ((TransactionDate <> ProcessingDate AND TransactionId in (2,3,9,14,15))
    OR
  (TransactionDate = ProcessingDate AND TransactionId in (2,3,9)))
```

But this gives me same result for both <> and = conditions
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Is your "TransactionDate" a full datetime, or is the time part all zeros? If it's a full datetime, it's likely that it'll never be equal to another. You might try explicitly casting both sides of the equality symbol to DATE() to see if that helps. Also, since 2, 3, and 9 are repeated... why not pull those out into its own clause and only check for the <> and transaction ID in 14, 15?

Comment: If `TransactionDate` and/or `ProcessingDate` can be null, you must be careful with comparisions, as both `TransactionDate = ProcessingDate` and `TransactionDate <> ProcessingDate` wouldn't include these.

Comment: The parentheses in the second query seem fine. What exactly is the problem? Are you getting too many rows or too few? Please show some data.

Comment: both scenarions <> and = gives the exact same data

Comment: Please provide a test case you think is wrong.

Comment: What does "both scenarios" mean? You have one condition with `<>` and one with `=` in your query and you get one result set for the combined criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible for both of those to return the same.  `<>` and `=` are mutually exclusive.  I suspect a problem with your testing or understanding.  Well if one of the dates is null then they would both return false.  No way they can both return true.

```
(
    (TransactionDate <> ProcessingDate AND TransactionId in (2, 3, 9, 14, 15))
    OR
    (TransactionDate =  ProcessingDate AND TransactionId in (2, 3, 9))
)
```

I will go out on limb here and assert

```
where TransactionDate <> ProcessingDate 
  and TransactionDate =  ProcessingDate
```

Will return zero rows every time

Answer (score 0):

Just organize better the parentheses like a math sentence

```
select  * from transactionDetails
WHERE OrderID in (400376, 400379)
AND`enter code here`
(
    (TransactionDate <> ProcessingDate AND TransactionId in (2,3,9,14,15))
    OR
  (TransactionDate = ProcessingDate AND TransactionId in (2,3,9))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answers, you might want to try using `UNION ALL` instead of `OR` and check which one is faster:

```
SELECT  * FROM transactionDetails
WHERE OrderID in (400376, 400379)
AND TransactionDate <> ProcessingDate 
AND TransactionId in (2,3,9,14,15)
UNION ALL
SELECT  * FROM transactionDetails
WHERE OrderID in (400376, 400379)
AND TransactionDate <> ProcessingDate 
AND TransactionDate = ProcessingDate 
AND TransactionId in (2,3,9)
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution you can use this.

```
select  * from transactionDetails
WHERE 
    OrderID in (400376, 400379)
    AND ( TransactionId in (2,3,9)
            OR ( TransactionDate <> ProcessingDate AND TransactionId IN (14,15) ) )
```